# "close behind" as in "time closes behind everyone and everything"

Tags: meaning

What does "close behind" mean in this sentence:

*"So life comes to an end and time **closes behind** everyone and everything."*

"life comes to an end" and "time closes behind everyone and everything" are in a parallel and should mean the same? But I still cannot figure our the metaphor. Thanks!

More context:

*So life comes to an end and time closes behind everyone and everything.
My ex-husband understood that and tried to escape by running away from it. I reminded him of time, being younger than he was, so he ran away from me too.*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is rather too simple for the ELU website.

Answer (score 2):

"time closes behind":

*conveys the idea of doors closing leaving you out, on the other side, in this specific case "on the other side of life", that is death"* . Is well suggests the closing of the life period as doors that by closing put an end to everyone and everything.